# SQLAlchemy include @property in query result?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

So I have a relationship between a movie and a category with a score and a amount of votes cast on them, I would like a property that checks if the score has enough votes to be shown on the site. so I created a @property (also tried hybrid_property) that just returns a bool, class below:

```
class MovieCategoryScores(db.Model):
    movie_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('movie.id'), primary_key=True)
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'), primary_key=True)
    score = db.Column(db.Integer)
    votes = db.Column(db.Integer)
    category = relationship("Category", back_populates="movies")
    movie = relationship("Movie", back_populates="categories")

    @hybrid_property
    def enough_votes(self):
        return self.votes >= 10
```

I am then performing this query, to get a rank and such, I'm guessing most of it is irrelevant to this:

```
def get_category_score(movie_id, category_id):
    query = db.session.query(
    MovieCategoryScores,
    func.rank()\
        .over(
            order_by=MovieCategoryScores.score.desc(),
            partition_by=MovieCategoryScores.category_id,
        )\
        .label('rank')
    )
    # now filter
    query = query.filter(MovieCategoryScores.category_id == category_id)
    query = query.order_by(MovieCategoryScores.category_id, 'rank')
    all_movies = query.subquery()
    new_query = db.session.query(all_movies).filter(all_movies.c.movie_id == movie_id)
    my_movie = new_query.first()
    return my_movie
```

However, this just returns `(550, 18, 853.4214743594645, 13, 1)` which is movie_id, person_id, score, votes and then rank. So I somehow want to also include the boolean from 'neoung_votes' in there, but I for the life of me can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways to overcome this issue:

1. Add `Assocation.enough_votes` in the first query.
2. Add `.filter(Association.enough_votes)` to the query (will only result in rows with enough_votes).
3. If you always want to return `enough_votes` on the query use a `column_property` instead of a `hybrid_property`:

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import column_property
class MovieCategoryScores(db.Model):
    ...
    enough_votes = column_property(votes >= 10)
    ...
```